# All sliders are moving in ListView.builder

Tags: flutter

I have ListView.builder in which I display data from my API call which has List of data after decoding. Among the data I have audio files. I also used Slider widget for this but all the slider move at once. I used Column inside ListView.builder to implement Slider and play pause button. Could anyone help me with this. Thank you.

```
ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: basicBooksSets.length,
                      itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
                        return Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                bottom:
                                    MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.04),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                basicBooksSets[i].imageSrc == null
                                    ? Container()
                                    : AspectRatio(
                                        aspectRatio: 1,
                                        child: PhotoView(
                                          backgroundDecoration:
                                              const BoxDecoration(
                                                  color: Colors.white),
                                          initialScale:
                                              PhotoViewComputedScale.contained *
                                                  0.8,
                                          imageProvider: NetworkImage(
                                              basicBooksSets[i].imageSrc!),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height:
                                      MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.04,
                                ),
                                basicBooksSets[i].audioSrc == null
                                    ? Container()
                                    : Column(
                                        children: [
                                          Slider(
                                              min: 0,
                                              max:
                                                  duration.inSeconds.toDouble(),
                                              value:
                                                  position.inSeconds.toDouble(),
                                              onChanged: (value) async {
                                                final position = Duration(
                                                    seconds: value.toInt());
                                                await audioPlayer
                                                    .seek(position);
                                              }),
                                          CircleAvatar(
                                            radius: 35,
                                            child: IconButton(
                                                onPressed: () async {
                                                  if (isPlaying) {
                                                    await audioPlayer.pause();
                                                  } else {
                                                    optionAudioPlay(
                                                        audioUrl:
                                                            basicBooksSets[i]
                                                                .audioSrc!,
                                                        optionIndex: i);
                                                  }
                                                },
                                                icon: Icon(isPlaying
                                                    ? Icons.pause
                                                    : Icons.play_arrow)),
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                Text(
                                  basicBooksSets[i].title.toString(),
                                  style: const TextStyle(
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height:
                                      MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.02,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ));
                      })
```

my optionAudioPlay function is as

```
void optionAudioPlay({
    required String audioUrl,
    int? optionIndex,
  }) async {
    // audioPlayer.dispose();
    // audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();

    if (opitonActiveAudioUrl == audioUrl) {
      setState(() {
        opitonActiveAudioUrl = null;
        opitonActiveAudioIndex = null;
        isPlaying = false;
      });
      return;
    }
    audioPlayer.onPlayerStateChanged.listen((state) {
      setState(() {
        isPlaying = state == PlayerState.PLAYING;
        myBoolList[optionIndex!] = state == PlayerState.PLAYING;
      });
    });

    audioPlayer.onDurationChanged.listen((newDuration) {
      setState(() {
        duration = newDuration;
      });
    });

    audioPlayer.onAudioPositionChanged.listen((newDuration) {
      setState(() {
        position = newDuration;
      });
    });

    audioPlayer.onPlayerCompletion.listen((state) {
      setState(() {
        isPlaying = false;
      });
    });

    await audioPlayer.play(audioUrl);
  }
```

Comment: Could you please share the listview builder code so we can identify where exactly the issue is.

Comment: This is my ListView.builder code and the function to play audio.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is something wrong with the code below. Here, you are setting the values to the position and all item have the reference of same position. So once you change position in slider, other slider values are also getting updated.

```
max:
                                                  duration.inSeconds.toDouble(),
                                              value:
                                                  position.inSeconds.toDouble(),
                                              onChanged: (value) async {
                                                final position = Duration(
                                                    seconds: value.toInt());
                                                await audioPlayer
                                                    .seek(position);
```

I believe this should be managed with **basicBooksSets[i]**. Please keep track of current position in each object and set the value from there like,

```
 Slider(
    min: 0,
    max:
    basicBooksSets[i].duration.inSeconds.toDouble(),
    value:
    basicBooksSets[i].position.inSeconds.toDouble(),
    onChanged: (value) async {
        setState((){
        final position = Duration(
            seconds: value.toInt());
            basicBooksSets[i].position = position;
        });
        await audioPlayer
            .seek(position);
    }),
```

Here, you are setting duration instead of it you need to set duration of specific item similar to you have update Play pause status but in Play pause you have prepared the separate list in this case use the list which you are passing to the listview

```
setState(() {
        duration = newDuration;
      });
```

Comment: This here basicBooksSets[i] is a List and it gives me error. I dont understand it, I am a beginner. Could there be any way to solve it

Comment: You need to add those variable in your list object. To keep the track of single object progress.

Comment: You are getting this duration and position from audio player correct? So when ever audio gets play, you need to update those values in the specific list item.

Comment: By using myBoolList[optionIndex!], I think you are managing the Play pause status and show it in respective item similarly you have the list of items, you need to set the progress of each item there and set it to the slider as I have shared